# Should I be able to use an adapter to compute the contents of a field when creating content?

Tags: plone, adapter, zope, dexterity

I am trying to create a report content type that contains a point-in-time snapshot of the contents of a custom container object over a time interval.  I will eventually be storing additional time-variable data with the list so generating the list just-in-time in a view will not quite work.

I have a content type for the report that includes the time interval and a field to hold the list of references to the container contents:

```
class IIssuesReport(form.Schema):
    report_begin_date = schema.Date(
        title=_(u"Report begin date"),
        )

    report_end_date = schema.Date(
        title=_(u"Report end date"),
        )

    issues = RelationList(
        title=_(u"Report Issues"),
        description=_(u'Select Issues'),
        default = [],
        value_type=RelationChoice(
            title=_(u'Issue'),
            default=[],
            source=ObjPathSourceBinder()
            ),
        required=False,
        )
```

I want to programatically populate the "issues" field when the form is submitted.  I believe I should be able to do this by writing an adapter that override the issues() property setter to generate and assign the data to the list.  I created a "populated" class with a factory to override the issues property setter:

```
class IPopulatedIssuesReport(interface.Interface):
    """A list of issues.
    """


class PopulateIssuesReport(object):
    """ Generate the IssuesReport issues from existing inventory
    """
    implements(IPopulatedIssuesReport)
    adapts(IIssuesReport)

    def __init__(self, context):
        self.context = context

    @property
    def issues(self):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

And registered the adapter factory:

```
<adapter factory=".issuesReport.PopulateIssuesReport" />
```

I patterned much of this after other posts about adapting INameFromTitle to use other separate fields, specifically [DavidJB's post](http://davidjb.com/blog/2010/04/plone-and-dexterity-working-with-computed-fields/):

When I created my IIssueReport content I expected to be dropped into the debugger in the adapter but it did not happen, as if the adapter never got executed.  What am I missing?  Is this the correct approach to populate this field with existing data from my site?

Comment: Does the IIssueReport interface need to be a behavior for this to work?  I would not think so.

Answer (score 1):

you should provide `provides` definition in adapter.

Try this !!

```
<adapter for="yourType.IIssuesReport"
         factory=".issuesReport.PopulateIssuesReport"
         provides=".issuesReport.IPopulateIssuesReport"
       />
```

Comment: Something is still amiss as this did not seem to work.  I currently have IIssuesReport, IPopulatedIssuesReport, and PopulateIssuesReport in the same issuesReport.py file.  Perhaps this is causing a conflict preventing this from working.  I will try splitting out the adapter into a separate file.

Comment: creat behaviors.py and move those code in it. Let see if that works. adapter defination for factor and provides will start with like `.behaviors.PopulateIssuesReport` and `.behaviors.IPopulateIssuesReport`

Comment: Moved the adapter code (interface and factory) to the a behaviors.py file and still see the same behavior: When I create the IIssuesReport content it completes the creation but I expected the adapter to run and stop in the debugger.  Other ideas what I may be missing?  Is there a way I can see that the adapter got registered and is available?

Comment: Thanks so much for helping here.  If I can get this figured out I need to turn it into a short tutorial.  To simplify I created a new project and stripped everything I think is non-essential out of the code.  I pasted all the code [here](http://pastebin.com/JcVF6Fyp).  Not sure this was the best way to paste it (with multiple files in one paste).  The past contains issuesReport.py, profiles/default/types/issuesReport.xml, interfaces.py, behaviors.py, and configure.zcml.  I am using Plone 4.1 (running on an Ubuntu system).

Comment: About the only thing I have not tried yet was to register a behavior and extend the behavior so this the same as the adapting INameFromTitle examples.  I would not expect this to be a requirement but perhaps there is an issue that makes this necessary?

Comment: Sorry, I will have a look very soon. Meanwhile, can you have a look https://github.com/webbyfox/GeorgeDrexler.grant Same sort of interface I've implemented